# What's the difference between knockout mappedRemove and mappedDestroy?

Tags: knockout-mapping-plugin

Couldn't find any documentation on this on the Knockout site, other than the knockout mapping plug in exposes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*sigh* - as soon as you post it - you find the answer.  Ironically via the knockout site : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html
and 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

> They are functionally equivalent to the regular ko.observableArray
>   functions, but can do things based on the key of the object.

So in brief:

mappedRemove and mappedRemoveAll removes an element in the same way that remove does, but allows you to do operations on the key.

mappedDestroy and mappedDestroyAll is there as a convenience for Ruby developers and adds _destroy to the object.  No idea why - I'm not a Ruby developer.